# Run one-line programs in parallel on separate lines

Tags: bash, shell-script, wget, gnu-parallel

So, let's say I have an array with a list of URLs, and I want to use something such as GNU parallel to download the URLs in parallel. A command like this would do the trick.

```
parallel -u wget -qc --show-progress ::: "${URLs[@]}"
```

The only issue with this command is while the progress of the commands is shown (especially since `-u` shows the output as it happens rather than waiting) the output of the commands all go to the same line. This results in a scenario in which when one wget instance outputs it overwrites the progress of the previous wget output on the tty. So, I was wondering how to have each wget output on it's own line at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parallel --ll wget -qc --show-progress ::: "${URLs[@]}"
```

The --ll option is in alpha testing, but works in my test.

Comment: Thanks. I should mention that this didn't work when using parallel from Ubuntu's apt repository (on 22.04). I had to download it from the GNU website and compile it.